# how to remove single quotes from a string, using replace

Tags: java, android, replace

How to replace below string.

```
String test =  "This is my Test's cases";
```

Now i am replacing "'" with space means like this "This is my Tests cases"
I tried:

```
  1) replace("'","")
  2) replaceAll("'","")
  3) replace("\'","")
```

... but i did not get any required results.

Test code:

```
String test = "The First American's style";
System.out.println("old text::"+test);      
test = test.replaceAll("'","\\'");
System.out.println("new text::"+test);
```

Comment: Your question title contradicts your example.

Comment: You don't have to escape an apostrophe inside a string literal. A (single) space is not an empty string (aka "null string") having no characters.

Comment: Your question says "Space" which doesn't mean "".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because question itself has an answer.

Answer (score 6):

This works fine:

```
    String test = "The First American's style";
    System.out.println("old text::"+test);      
    test = test.replaceAll("'","");
    System.out.println("new text::"+test);
```

Output:

```
old text::The First American's style
new text::The First Americans style
```

Comment: I really feel the question is broken, as the OP mentioned he did try `replace.All("'", "")`. Still, you're the only who tried to understand what the OP really needs (*not what he deserves*), hence +1 from me. )

Answer (score 2):

When you want to replace `'` with space, why don't you do so?

```
test = test.replaceAll("'", " ");
```

Comment: This is simply not true, just running it and getting `new text::The First American s style` as a result.

Comment: Do you think there's any meaning in replacing `Text's` with `Text s`?

Comment: @raina77ow Yes, because when OP successfully replaced one specific char with another, he is free to use any character available.

Comment: SIgh... in the perfect world, your approach is perfect too. Sadly, SO is not the one. The OP did mention that he already 'tried' using `replaceAll("'", "")` (which should've suit him). Your solution will be just another tool in the toolbox that doesn't have any sense for him, most probably. The right way, I think, is to understand what was wrong with the OP's approach in the first place.

Comment: OP tried this solution but made a mistake.Op did not leave space, his/her approach was `replaceAll("'","")`, what OP should have used is `replaceAll("'"," ")`(see the second parameter of replaceAll).

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hey replace string's name.");
System.out.println("Old String::"+sb.toString());      
System.out.println("New String::"+sb.toString().replaceAll("'", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ASCII,unicode values to replace single quotes..

```
    test = test.replaceAll((char)145,"");
otherwise  
     test = test.replaceAll(\u0091,"");
```

for more information http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0091/index.htm

done enjoy....

Answer (score -1):

```
test = test.replace("\\'", " ");
```

or

```
test = test.replace("\'", " ");
```